# The With statement in the VBS code, how expressed in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Is there a software or tool that can quickly convert VBS code into PowerShell code?

In addition, I want to know, the following `With` statement in the VBS code, how to express in PowerShell?

The `With` statement is great, it can shorten the code, can I implement similar functions in PowerShell?

I found the PowerShell code very succinct, I am very curious to know that the above code, how to use the shortest PowerShell code to achieve the same functionality.

```vb
'declare and instaciate wrdApp
Dim wrdApp: Set wrdApp = WScript.CreateObject("Word.Application")
'declare wrdDoc
Dim wrdDoc
Dim wdReplaceAll

'Open the document
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("c:\test.docx")

'set the value for the replace "constant"
wdReplaceAll = 2

wrdDoc.Select

With wrdApp.Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "WordToReplace"
    .Replacement.Text = "ReplaceWith"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = 1
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
'the Replace argument is the 11'th argument 
    .Execute , , , , , , , , , , wdReplaceAll
End With

'save the document and close Word
wrdDoc.SaveAs2 "c:\test-ok.docx"
wrdApp.Quit

'clean up
Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
```

Comment: It's always better to ask yourself: 'What exactly do I want to do?' rather than 'How do I convert this to something else?' What exactly do you want to do and what have you tried so far? Saying that this looks like a good resource for VB to PowerShell equivalents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't have an equivalent for VBScript's `With` statement. Instead of

```vb
With wrdApp.Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    ...
End With
```

you'd probably do something like this:

```bsh
$find = $wrdApp.Selection.Find
$find.ClearFormatting()
$find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
...
```

or like this:

```bsh
$wrdApp.Selection.Find | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ClearFormatting()
    $_.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
    ...
}
```

Also, to my knowledge there is no VBScript or VBA to PowerShell compiler. I put together some notes on how to [translate VBA code to PowerShell](https://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2psh.shtml), though.

Comment: How does this code use powershell?
---
    .Execute , , , , , , , , , , wdReplaceAll
---