# PowerShell equivalent of vbscript "with" statement?

Tags: powershell

Is there a PowerShell equivalent of the vbscript "with" statement?  e.g.

```
With MyLabel
   .Height = 2000
   .Width = 2000
   .Caption = "This is MyLabel"
End With
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The With statement in the VBS code, how expressed in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459455/the-with-statement-in-the-vbs-code-how-expressed-in-powershell) or [Setting multiple properties at once - equivalent of VB's With statement to provide an implied object context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42378637/150605)

Comment: In short: there's no equivalent feature. In the common scenario of object initialization with many property values, PowerShell's type conversion magic usually makes it pretty easy to write in compact ways.